# Why involving circular definitions in polymorphic funtions will cause some problem of the definition of type?

Tags: type-systems, category-theory

> There are problem with polymorphic functions that involve circular definitions, and with the fact that you can't have a set of all sets.

The sentence above is from [types-and-functions](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/24/types-and-functions/), in which Bartos Milewski gives some classes about category theory. Before the apperance of the sentence, Bartos Milewski gives the intuition definition of type, which is the set of value.It's hard for me to understand what situiation the sentence is talking about. Can anyone give me some example? About why polymorphic functions that involve cirucular definitions will cause some problem of the definition that type is the set of value? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

A parametrically polymorphic type uses a universal quantifier: for all types `a`. This is circular, because it means that `a` must also include the type that you are defining right now.